# Как убрать пустые строки в элементе списка?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, строки, текст

Как убрать пустые строки **из** элемента списка (т.е. **не** сам пустой элемент списка)

Пример:

```
[<tr class="sample">
<td>


<tr>
</tr>


<td id="ess8key-8">TEXTEXTEXTEXTEXTEX</td>

<td class="sample-class" id="sample-id-8">TEXTEXTEXTEXTEXTEX</td>

</tr>
<tr>


</tr>


</td>

</tr>, <tr class="sample">
<td>


<tr>
<td colspan="2"><strong>TITLE:</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="sample-class" id="sample-id-1">TEXTEXTEXTEXTEXTEX</td>


<td>

</td>
</tr>]
```

желаемое:

```
[<tr class="sample">
<td>
<tr>
</tr>
<td id="ess8key-8">TEXTEXTEXTEXTEXTEX</td>
<td class="sample-class" id="sample-id-8">TEXTEXTEXTEXTEXTEX</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</td>
</tr>, <tr class="sample">
<td>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><strong>TITLE:</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="sample-class" id="sample-id-1">TEXTEXTEXTEXTEXTEX</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С регулярками:

```
import re
p = re.compile('\n{2,}')
oldtext = '''
adsffgsf
fsafds


fdsafsf
adfsfas


sdfasf'''
newtext = p.sub('\n', oldtext)
# newtext = p.sub('\n', oldtext).strip('\n') - если в начале конце тоже не должно быть пустых строк 
print (newtext)
```

Comment: Пустые строки в начале и конце останутся. Но это можно решить с помощью `"\n  blabla  \n".strip("\n")`.

Comment: @pank я посчитал, что пустая строка в начале/конце может быть "особым" случаем, а так Вы правы.

Comment: А что означает эта строка?
`p = re.compile('\n{2,}')`

Comment: @C.Anon - скомпилированное регулярное выражение. Перевод строки, встречающийся 2 или более раз подряд. Кстати, строка, состоящая из пробелов - не считается пустой.

Comment: @andy.37 А не лучше ли подойдет `\s`, вместо `\n`?

Comment: @C.Anon Нет, потому что я сомневаюсь, что замена двух *пробелов* подряд на символ перевода строки - то, что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Так можно удалить пустые строки из одной строки:

```
s1 = """
Ваш текст с пустыми строками
"""

s2 = "\n".join(filter(bool, s1.splitlines())) # Удаляем пустые строки
```

А так из каждого элемента списка:

```
a1 = [s1, s1 + "last line"] # массив строк
# удаляем пустые строки из элементов массива
a2 = list(map(lambda x: "\n".join(filter(bool, x.splitlines())), a1))
```